# How can I validate a phone number input of several variations?

Tags: java

My program currently validates the phone number only when it is ten consecutive numbers and characters and it closes when the word "exit" is typed. However, I was wondering how I could validate the numbers if they were also written as both, for example, (123)456-7890 and 123-456-7890

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Q2
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true){
        System.out.print("Enter your phone number: ");
        String number=kb.next();
        if(number.equals("exit")){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    boolean valid=true;
    for(int i=0;i<number.length();i++){
        if(number.length()!=10) valid=false;
    }
    if (valid) System.out.println("It is valid");
    else System.out.println("It is invalid");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just [Regular Expressions](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

You do that by doing **real** validation.

Meaning: "validation" describes the process of checking your input against a **set of rules**. If the input conforms to **all** those rules, it is valid; otherwise it is not.

So, yes, checking the length was a first simple rule; but "length is 10" ... just turns out to not be a good rule. For example, "123456A90" has length 10; but is invalid.

What you can do instead (just giving you some ideas):

- use regular expressions (or plain string parsing) in order to determine if your input string *matches* a certain pattern, like (nnn-nnnn-nnnn)
- simple replace all "unwanted" characters, such as ( ) - with ""; and then you check if the resulting string has length 10.

  So, the answer is: have a close look at your input and determine the properties that *valid* phone numbers have in common. And then you start writing code to check those.

Comment: I think the only valid solution it's your first bullet: Regular Expressions. The second one would accept a phone number like 0(-1---2(3456789

Comment: @bra_racing There is always more than one way to do things. When you do a replaceAll() with "good patterns" (like only replace a single hyphen between two numbers, that could work, too). The point is: he is a newbie; and therefore focusing on "here use regexes" takes out a lot of the "variety" that such problems provide. Learning to program is learning to understand and explore the option space ;-)

Comment: Totally right, I've just pointed that a simple replacement without controlling a good pattern is not a valid solution. But of course, I strongly agree with you that here the key is deal with the problem just investigating and programming

Answer (score 0):

Why you simply don't use regex like this its more powerful :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("123-456-7890 is valid? " + valider("123-456-7890"));
    System.out.println("(123)456-7890 is valid? " + valider("(123)456-7890"));
}

private static boolean valider(String phoneNumber) {
    if (phoneNumber.matches("\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{4}")) {
        return true;
    } else return phoneNumber.matches("\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d{3}-\\d{4}");
}
```